# Lookup value in column based on table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table:

```
I C     H   O   P   S   T   C   D   E   M   V   W   R
4.76                04  08  04  05  04  04  08      
5.56                05  09  05  06  05  05  09  03  
6.35    03  02  04  06  11  06  07  06  06  11  04  06
7.94    04  03  05  07  13  08  09  08  07  13  05  08
9.525   05  04  07  09  16  09  11  09  09  16  06  10
12.7    07  05  09  12  22  12  15  13  12  22  08  12
15.875  09  06  11  15  27  16  19  16  15  27  10  15
19.05   11  07  13  19  33  19  23  19  19  33  13  19
25.4    14  10  18  25  44  25  31  26  25  44  17  25
31.75   18  13  23  31  54  32  38  32  31  54  21  31
```

Given these two inputs:

- a letter corresponding to one of the other headers (H    O   P   S   T   C   D   E   M   V   W   R) and
- a number which is in the column with that header,

I want to lookup the value in column `I C` which is on the same row as that number.

For example: with `W` and `03` as inputs, the formula would return `5.56`.

How do I do this using an Excel formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the letter in `A14` and the "number" in `B14` you can use the formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:A11,MATCH(B14,OFFSET(A1:A11,0,MATCH(A14,A1:M1,0)-1)))
```

[image: Screenshot]

Explaining from inside out:
    - `MATCH(A14,A1:M1,0)` will find the column number of the letter
    - `OFFSET(A1:A11,0,MATCH(...)-1` then gives the array of that column
    - `MATCH(B14,OFFSET(...` gives the match of the value in that column (row number)
    - `INDEX(A1:A11,MATCH...` gives the value in that column

Comment: QUICK RESPONSE AND EFFECTIVE RESULTS ARE REALLY APPRECIABLE. I AM KIND OF SURPRISED TO SEE THAT WORKED THANKS A LOT